# Shortcut to switch keyboards

Tags: phonetics

I have the Linguist's Software IPA Unicode font, which requires a separate keyboard--internal, not external. I have Mac OS 11.5.1 and have created keyboard shortcuts within Word to switch from one font to another, but not from one keyboard to another. I have the keyboard icon on the menu bar, and have to manually select the IPA keyboard every time I want to type IPA.
Anyone know how to create a shortcut?

Comment: Unless you need to type long passages in IPA, the Mac Character menu seems easier and more convenient than switching keyboards. Almost everything in IPA is available in Unicode. The menu is at the bottom of the Edit menu on almost every Mac application (except Word, of course, which won't play by Apple rules), but you can get the characters and copy/paste in Word.

Answer (score 2):

*Super User* has some answers on switching keyboard layouts by hotkeys on a Mac: [here](https://superuser.com/a/550542/1420), [here](https://superuser.com/a/678061/1420), [here](https://superuser.com/a/13498/1420).

[This article](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/change-keyboard-input-language-mac/) (with screenshots) walks you through the process of setting custom hotkeys for switching keyboards.

The default hotkeys seem to be `Command`+`Space` and `Ctrl`+`Command`+`Space`, which cycle through the list of keyboards. Apparently, you cannot assign a shortcut to a specific keyboard layout.

If your questions refers to changing the keyboard layout from within Word, I would doubt whether an system-wide operation would generally be supported inside an application.

Comment: Newer Apple laptops have a dedicated globe key (bottom left) which switches keyboard layouts with a single click by default.

Comment: The suggested article seems to provide the solution. Thanks very much!

Comment: @WilliamOdom - if an answer turns out to be the solution that worked for you, you can click on the check mark to its left. This indicates that it was a working solution for you, and also gives the person who provided the answer some "rep" on this site.